# ipfs.cat returns "undefined" object in React-native

Tags: buffer, react-native, undefined, cat, ipfs

**On React-native:**
When I add a buffered string(i.e. Buffer(str) ) to IPFS using ipfs.add, the buffered string is added successfully and IPFS returns the hash.

When I try to retrieve the buffered string via ipfs.cat and the hash, ipfs.cat returns  "undefined".

**On Node.jS and ReactJs:**
I do not have this problem. Both ipfs.add and ipfs.cat works.

*Is the problem related to pinning in IPFS? or would changing the ipfs-api version in packag.json help?*

Any help would be highly appreciated.

**Below is the app.js code used for React-Native**

```
import React, {useState, useRef} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Text, View, StatusBar, Button} from 'react-native';

const CryptoJS = require('crypto-js');
const ipfsAPI = require('ipfs-api');
// Connceting to the ipfs network via infura gateway
const ipfs = ipfsAPI('ipfs.infura.io', '5001', {protocol: 'https'});

export default function App() {
  const [number, setNumber] = useState(0);
  const [hash, setHash] = useState(' ');
  console.log('printing: ', number);
  //console.log('testing:', ipfs);


  const handleCaseAdd = () => {
    setNumber(1);

    // Encrypt
    const ciphertext = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(
      JSON.stringify('my message'),
      'secret key 1234',
    ).toString();
    console.log(' Ciphertext: ', ciphertext); // 'ciphertext
    console.log('Buffered ciphertext: ', Buffer(ciphertext));

    // Adding the encrpyted file to IPFS
    ipfs.add(Buffer(ciphertext), {pin: true}, (error, result) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return;
      }
      setHash(result[0].hash);
      console.log('File added succesfully');
      console.log('IPFS result: ', result);

    });
  }; // end of the function

  const handleCaseGet = fileHash => {
    //const fileHash = hash;
    console.log('fileHash (before) :', fileHash);

    ipfs.files.cat(fileHash, function(err, bufferedCiphertext) {
      console.log('fileHash (after) :', fileHash);
      console.log('Getting Buffered ciphertext: ', bufferedCiphertext);


    });
  }; // end of the function

  //let confirmed;
  //confirmed = true;
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.first}>
        <View style={styles.box1} />
        <View style={styles.box2} />
      </View>
      <View>
        <Button title="Add" onPress={handleCaseAdd} />
      </View>

      <Text> Number: {number} </Text>
      <Text> Hash: {hash} </Text>
      <View>
        <Button title="Get" onPress={handleCaseGet.bind(this, hash)} />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    //alignItems: "center",
    //justifyContent: "center",
    paddingTop: StatusBar.currentHeight,
  },
  first: {
    backgroundColor: 'green',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    alignItems: 'flex-start',
  },

  box1: {
    backgroundColor: 'dodgerblue',
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    //flex: 1,
  },
  box2: {
    backgroundColor: 'gold',
    width: 50,
    height: 50,

    //alignSelf: "flex-start",
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`ipfs-api` has been deprecated for two years, the replacement is `ipfs-http-client` - could you please try with that module instead?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ipfs-http-client

Comment: I tried to import and use  the ipfs-http-client in my code. However, I got the following error:

"error: not implemented"

I am using
"ipfs-http-client": "^42.0.0",
    "node-libs-react-native": "^1.2.0",
    "react": "16.11.0",
    "react-native": "0.62.2",